# Using datastore in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I begin to develop on app engine with python 2.7 and I'm really confuse with the datastore and ancestors / keys / parents.

As an example, I'm trying to develop a simple forum with categories,subjects and response.

I don't find the way to represent relation and use them. I've explored and explored again the documentation, but I can't implement it.

Can you share sample of code that explain relations between entity and query you use to store and to get data?

This is my class in models.py

```
class UserInfo(db.Model):
    Email = db.EmailProperty()
    pseudo = db.StringProperty()
    UserID = db.StringProperty()

class Sujet(db.Model):
    Titre = db.StringProperty()
    Auteur = db.StringProperty()
    Date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Message(db.Model):
    Auteur = db.StringProperty()
    sujet = db.ReferenceProperty(Sujet, collection_name='messages')
    Date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    Message = db.TextProperty()
```

My post method:

```
def post (self):
    UserID = users.get_current_user().user_id()
    query = UserInfo.all()
    query.filter('UserID =',UserID)
    User_query = query.get()
    Auteur = User_query.pseudo
    Titre = self.request.get('titre')

    if Titre:
        sujet = Sujet()
        sujet.Auteur = Auteur
        sujet.Titre = Titre
        sujet.put()
        message = Message()
        message.Auteur = Auteur
        message.sujet = sujet
        message.Message = self.request.get('message')
        message.put()
    else:
        sujet = Sujet.all()
        sujet = sujet.filter('Titre =',self.request.get('sujet'))
        sujet = sujet.get()
        message = Message()
        message.Auteur = Auteur
        message.sujet = sujet
        message.Message = self.request.get('message')
        message.put()
```

I have to action. Create a new 'sujet' if Titre exist or a new message if not. My problem is that when i create a 'sujet' the reference property works well, but when i try to add a message, the reference property is set to none...

my html to add a sujet:

```
<h4>Nouveau sujet</h4>
<form action="/index/forum" method="post">
    <div><input type="text" name="titre" placeholder="Titre " size="24"</div>
    <div><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="30" size="24"></textarea></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Créer" class="btn"></div>
</form>
```

And to add a message to an existing one :

```
<h3>{{ sujet.Titre }}</h3>
<div>
    <form action="/index/forum" method="post">
        <div><input type="hidden" name="sujet" value="{{ sujet.Titre }} " size="24" </div>
        <div><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="30" size="24"></textarea></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Répondre" class="btn"></div>
      </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What code have you tried? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: suggest you buy a book, this covers exactly what you are asking for in a tutorial format: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Code-Cloud-Pragmatic-Programmers-Chu-Carroll/dp/1934356638/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1353423917&sr=8-2

Answer (score 0):

Download a working application then, this is very similar to what you want:

[GuestBook Example](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/guestbook)

```
greetings = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Greeting ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10")

for greeting in greetings:
  if greeting.author:
    self.response.out.write('<b>%s</b> wrote:' % greeting.author.nickname())
  else:
    self.response.out.write('An anonymous person wrote:')
  self.response.out.write('<blockquote>%s</blockquote>' %
                          cgi.escape(greeting.content))
```

Comment: Yes this is the basic, my problem is more about relations, and the way to filter on entities with the relation with others.

Comment: Then you are out of luck as there is no better documentation then the official documentation. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Ancestor_Paths https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_ancestor